# error CS0433: The imported type `System.Net.WebRequest' is defined multiple times

Tags: c#, webrequest

when i'm loading my C# script, i get the error message in title.

My script starts with these lines:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TradeServer.ScriptingDriver.DataObjects;
using TradeServer.ScriptingDriver.Interfaces
```

;

ANd the error comes from that first line:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://drive.google.com/file/d/....");
WebResponse webResp = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream());
string newestversion = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I've tried to comment out pretty much all permutations, it just does not work, creates more error codes, or always spits out error in title.

I understand from searching on Google that i have some kind of duplicate issues in my libraries, but i'm really no expert on this.

If anyone 's got a clue how to fix this. Appreciated.

Comment: more info from the compiler:2017-07-12 19:24:27     |DEBUG| csscript.CompilerException: (81,5): error CS0433: The imported type `System.Net.WebRequest' is defined multiple times
(1,1): warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `System.dll'

Comment: 2017-07-12 19:24:27     |DEBUG| csscript.CompilerException: (81,5): error CS0433: The imported type `System.Net.WebRequest' is defined multiple times
(1,1): warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `System.dll'

   at CSScriptLibrary.MonoEvaluator.HandleCompilingErrors(Action action)
   at CSScriptLibrary.MonoEvaluator.CompileCode(String scriptText)
   at CSScriptLibrary.MonoEvaluator.LoadCode[T](String scriptText, Object[] args)

Comment: at CSScriptLibrary.MonoEvaluator.LoadFile[T](String scriptFile)
   at TradeServer.TradeLogicDriver.Indicators.ScriptIndicator.()
2017-07-12 19:24:27     |LOCALAPI|      Could not load script at location 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\HTS\ScriptIndicators\myNakedIndicator.cs'. Error: (81,5): error CS0433: The imported type `System.Net.WebRequest' is defined multiple times
(1,1): warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `System.dll'

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is happening because you have two different assemblies being referenced that contain a type of the same name `WebRequest`.

You'll want to be explicit about which assemblies' `WebRequest` type you want to use. In your case try:

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://drive.google.com/file/d/....");
```

**Update**:

Here's a way to get more information about what exactly is causing this conflict. Try putting this in before the line throwing the original error. It should cause a new error but this time we should see more information about those conflicting sources.

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribut‌​e x = null;`

This should tell you something like:

> The type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribut‌​e' exists in both 'c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll' and .....

Comment: yes, that's what i gathered from searching around. But do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: Are you saying your still getting these errors after trying this?

Comment: yes, my code was like this before. I tried again with your proposal, still get:

Comment: 2017-07-12 19:35:46     |LOCALAPI|      Could not load script at location 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\HTS\ScriptIndicators\myNakedIndicator.cs'. Error: (81,16): error CS0433: The imported type `System.Net.WebRequest' is defined multiple times
(1,1): warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `System.dll'

Comment: How about the second line: WebResponse, i also need to change it ?

Comment: Adding your line above, i get:

Comment: Could not load script at location 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\HTS\ScriptIndicators\myNakedIndicator.cs'. Error: (80,65): error CS1056: Unexpected character `?'
(1,1): warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `System.dll'

Comment: that's my line 80 now:

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.DefaultParameterValueAttribut‌​e x = null;

Comment: not sure why it complains about unexpected character ?'

Comment: Can you tell me what your solution references, i.e. from the references drop down in solution explorer assuming your using VS.

Comment: Also, try to clean up all references and using statements.